# Добавление элемента списка в избранное

Tags: javascript

Хочу реализовать такое функционирование: есть список с документами. Рядом с каждым документом есть кнопка для добавления определённого документа в избранное (в форме флажка или сердечка, сейчас это не так важно). Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку добавления документа в избранное, то этот элемент списка с документом отправляется в другой список избранных документов уже на другой странице. Самое главное, чтобы сохранённые документы в избранных хранились в localStorage.

У меня что-то получилось, но код добавляет документ в закладки не на той странице, где должен храниться, а на той же, где все документы. Желательно просто подсказать принцип правильной работы такого функционала добавления в избранное, чтобы я своим умом пришёл к нужному результату.

Вопросы, которые меня интересуют больше всего (я перерыл интернет ресурсы, но, к сожалению, не нашёл ответов на нужные мне вопросы), и я был бы очень рад получить на них ответы (или хотя бы направить моё мышление в нужное русло):

1. Для хранения документов в localStorage мне необходимо каждому документу присваивать ключ и значение, или я могу хранить весь список документов в избранном, задав ему одно значение и ключ?
2. Для того, чтобы добавленный документ в закладках сохранялся на отдельной странице, нужно ли мне присваивать каждому элементу дата-атрибут с уникальным номером документа? (Потому что без добавления доп. атрибутов я смог сделать добавление в избранное, но на той же странице со всеми документами).

Comment: Для хранения избранного в localStorage вам нужен всего лишь один ключ (к примеру favourites) и там хранить данные типа [ {id:1,name:'index'}, {id:2,name:'candy'}, ...].

Comment: Когда перерывали интернет, то не находили [это](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?